# Can't create handler inside thread - Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I am getting this error from my android log and I have looked to other threads that have this kind of problem but i still cannot fix my own problem

Basically, i would like to update my UI from service class by callback mechanism

```
//this method is inside the fragment class
public void updateProgress(int progress){
    switch(progress){
        case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_VALIDATE_USER:
            pdPostUserLoading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Registration", "Validating user...", true, false);
            break;
        case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_POSTING_DATA:
            pdPostUserLoading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Registration", "Posting data...", true, false);
            break;
        case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_OPEN_CONNECTION:
            pdPostUserLoading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Registration", "Open connection...", true, false);
            break;
        case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_OBTAINING_RESPONSE:
            pdPostUserLoading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Registration", "Obtaining Response...", true, false);
            break;
        case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_DISMISS:
            if(pdPostUserLoading != null)
                pdPostUserLoading.dismiss();
            break;


    }
}
```

Then i called this statement from processor class (which is called from the service class)

```
callback.updateProgress(Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_OPEN_CONNECTION);
```

From the service class

```
public interface Callback {
    void updateProgress(int progress);
}

class Task implements  Runnable{
    public void run(){
        PostNewUserProcessor processor  = new PostNewUserProcessor(mCallback);
        boolean valid = processor.postUser(newUser);

        if(valid){
            //Todo
        }
        else{
            //TODO
        }
    }

public void postUser(Bundle data){

        //Retrieve data from the intent
    newUser = data.getParcelable(Constants.NEW_USER);

    new Thread(new Task());
}
```

Log error

```
07-18 18:52:44.994    8942-9612/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1137
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
            at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:108)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:110)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
            at com.robertlimantoproject.bookreviewapp.activity.RegistrationPageFragment.updateProgress(RegistrationPageFragment.java:354)
            at com.robertlimantoproject.bookreviewapp.processor.PostNewUserProcessor.postUser(PostNewUserProcessor.java:81)
            at com.robertlimantoproject.bookreviewapp.service.PostNewUserService$Task.run(PostNewUserService.java:61)
            at com.robertlimantoproject.bookreviewapp.utils.Util$1.run(Util.java:36)
```

Comment: what problem are you talking about?

Comment: I am sorry, i just finished editing the post, could u take a look again?

Comment: can you see "Related" section on the right side of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `PostNewUserProcessor processor  = new PostNewUserProcessor(mCallback);` from a non-UI thread.

But showing a dialog should be written in the UI thread. like this..

```
 case Constants.ProgressUIPostUser.PD_VALIDATE_USER:
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                pdPostUserLoading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Registration", "Validating user...", true, false);

            }
        });
            break;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!!! i still do not know why it is not in the main by default since i have put the method inside the activity-fragment which suppose to be the main thread? could you explain to me?

Comment: How do i put this as an answer in my post?

Comment: As i said you are passing the callback **PostNewUserProcessor processor  = new PostNewUserProcessor(mCallback);** in a non UI thread. Then the callback method **updateProgress()** will work in the same thread where it is called from. i. e the non UI thread.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro :D

Answer (score 0):

Just Add

```
Looper.prepare();
```

inside your thread as the first statement.

Learn more about Looper threads by reading :

[Looper Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you forgot to add looper.prepare inside your thread. 
Take a look here:

[Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-which-has-not-called-looper-prepare) and 
[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972028/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare-in-andro). 
Next, in order to implement what you want take a look here:
[Can't see ProgressDialog while AsyncTask run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752210/cant-see-progressdialog-while-asynctask-run-in-background) 
Tutorial:
http://www.41post.com/4588/programming/android-coding-a-loading-screen-part-1